# dojox/gesture/swipe prevents the html select to open dropdown

Tags: select, dojo, swipe

can anyone please explain to me why the html SELECT control (or any other control like BUTTON) placed inside the div (that is registered with dojox/gesture/swipe events) cannot be opened? I'd welcome any workarounds pls

```
require({
}, [ 'dojo/dom', 'dojox/gesture/swipe', 'dojo/on', 'dojo/_base/event' ], function(dom, swipe, on, event) {
    var div = dom.byId('testSwipe');
    var isSwipe = false;

    on(div, swipe.end, function(e) {
        console.log("### SWIPE");        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLyck884/

Answer (score 0):

based on the documentation here, particularly the image : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/gesture.html

the image depicts how the dojo standardizes the events (also for desktops) and how the swipe is just another layer of the touch events. so I reckoned if the mouse events are replaced by touchstart or something, then it most likely blocks the default mouse action...

once I've stopped propagating the event (on the SELECT) further, then it worked ok.

```
query("select", this.domNode).on(touch.press, function(e){e.stopPropagation()});
```

where this.domNode is the element on which the swipe is enabled

```
on(this.domNode, swipe, lang.hitch(this, "_onSwipe"));
```

Unfortunately the swipe (touch) event overriding the default behaviour is not very handy, I just left dojox/gesture/swipe or touch for now. Seems like I'll rather implement my own touch event handling.